# Origin of the term dual space?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Basically, why is a dual vector space called as such? Is the reason for the term *"dual"* simply because the two vector spaces are related by a one-to-one mapping, or is there something more to it?

Sorry for such a basic question, but I've never been able to find a definitive answer so far.

Comment: I would guess that most names in math don't come from a committee sitting down for years discussing what the most insightful name would be -- some bloke just chooses a name which seems appropriate.  So I'd guess it's called the dual space because it forms a pair with the space it's the dual of -- and "dual" means "$2$".

Comment: Typically, the term *dual* is applied when the dual of the dual is the original object. Wikipedia has a [host of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)).

Comment: one-to-one but no natural choice of such a mapping. If you put a positive definite inner product on the original space, this provides a specific mapping, given $v$ we define $v^ast$ by $v^\ast(w) = \langle v,w \rangle$

Comment: Usually, there is no one-to-one  mapping between a vector space and it's dual... And if you're talking about algebrical dual (and not topological dual), the cardinal of the dual is strictly greater than the cardinal of the "base" vector space for infinite vector spaces.

Comment: The preamble to [this blog entry of T.Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/the-uncertainty-principle/) contains his view on the term "duality". HTH

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far - I understand that it's not a term that's agreed upon, but I was just trying to go an intuition as to why it's called that, whether it refers to something about the relationship, e.g. is it that they form a pair as the dual of a dual space is naturally isomorphic to the "original" vector space?!

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro   In Terence Tao's preamble what does he mean by *"A vector space $V$ over a field $F$ can be described either by the set of vectors inside $V$, or dually by the set of linear functionals $\lambda: V \rightarrow F$ from $V$ to the field $F$ (or equivalently, the set of vectors inside the dual space $V^*$)"*? Is it meant that you can either describe a vector in terms of a given basis for $V$ or by linear maps which provide a way of determining it's components with respect to a given basis for $V$?!

Answer (score 3):

*In one of the comments to the original question, Will says*:

"@GiuseppeNegro In Terence Tao's preamble [reference to [this blog entry](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/the-uncertainty-principle/)] what does he mean by "A vector space V over a field F can be described either by the set of vectors inside V, or dually by the set of linear functionals λ:V→F from V to the field F (or equivalently, the set of vectors inside the dual space V∗)"? Is it meant that you can either describe a vector in terms of a given basis for V or by linear maps which provide a way of determining it's components with respect to a given basis for V?"

*Here's my answer*.

"Of course: if $V$ is finite dimensional then you can interpret that statement in terms of bases, like you did. But the principle is more general, as you can also give a more intrinsic interpretation that does not use bases and coordinates (actually it does, but in a silent way).

Namely, let $v, w\in V$ be vectors. Assume that $f(v)=f(w)$ for all dual vectors (or linear functionals) $f$. Then (**claim**) $v=w$.

*Proof*. Let $x=v-w$. We need to show that $x=0$. Suppose not. Then there exist a basis of $V$ that contains $x$:
$$\left\{x, e_\alpha\ :\ \alpha\in A\right\}$$
Here $A$ is some index set, possibly infinite (in which case, the existence of such a basis is a consequence of the axiom of choice). So any vector in $V$ is uniquely described by a sum $$\lambda x+\sum_{\alpha\in A}\lambda_\alpha e_\alpha, $$ where $\lambda_\alpha\ne 0$ for at most a finite number of indices $\alpha\in A$. (So that sum over $A$ is actually a finite sum).  Define a linear functional $$f\left(\lambda x+ \sum_{\alpha\in A}\lambda_\alpha e_\alpha\right)=\lambda.$$
This functional has the property that $f(x)=1$. But our assumptions give that $f(x)=0$. This is a contradiction, therefore $x=0$, as claimed. $\square$

This statement says if you know how all linear functionals act on a vector, then you know the vector itself with no possible ambiguity. It is a general principle that is widely used in many fields of mathematics, as far as I know."

Comment: So is the concept of duality in this sense is that they are connected to one another in that if you know the dual space then you know the original vector space and vice versa?!

Comment: Maybe that's true, I don't know. However, I hear that, in the case of topological vector spaces, there exist spaces that are not isomorphic yet they have the same dual space. Those are technicalities for the specialists, that's not the point of the present discussion: I just want to emphasize that dual spaces are not there to classify vector spaces.  It is the *pairing* $V^\star\times V\to K$ that is interesting. You can choose to work on vectors $v\in V$ directly, or to work on the action of $V^\star$ through this pairing.

Comment: "You can choose to work on vectors v∈V directly, or to work on the action of V⋆ through this pairing. " this is the part I'm confused about. Is it that their pairing maps to the field $K$ over which the vector field $V$ is defined?

Comment: @Will: Yes, $K$ is the scalar field.

Comment: Does the duality follow from the fact that we can consider dual vectors as linear functionals acting on vectors, but we can equally consider vectors as linear functionals acting on dual vectors (as the double dual is naturally isomorphic to the "original" vector space)?

Comment: ...This wiki article  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_pair seems to be quite good at explaining the concept also (in particular, the introductory paragraph). What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to study etymology of math, but here is one possible reason for the nomenclature.

The intuition for duality is that the dual of dual equals itself. For example, in set theory, the dual of a set $S \subset \mathbb{S}$ is its complement, $S^c = \{x \in \mathbb{S} : x \notin S\}$. It is obvious that $(S^{c})^{c} = S$.

Let us apply this intuition to vector space:

For a vector space $V$ of finite dimension $r$ over the field $F$, recall the definition of dual space $V^* = \text{hom}(V, \mathbb{R})$, i.e., $V^*$ is the set of all linear maps between $V$ and real number. $V^*$ is also a vector space of dimension $r$ over $F$. To see this, we can construct basis of $V^*$ from the basis of $V$. For $n = 1, 2, \cdots , r$; $v \in V$; $\beta = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n\}$ where $v_i$ are basis of $V$, we defined $v_1^*, \cdots v_n^*$ as:
$$
v^*_1(v) = \begin{cases}
1_F & \text{if } v = v_1 \\
0_F & \text{if } v \in \beta \setminus \{v_1\}
\end{cases}
v^*_n(v) = \begin{cases}
1_F & \text{if } v = v_n \\
0_F & \text{if } v \in \beta \setminus \{v_n\}
\end{cases}
$$

$v_i^{*}$ are basis of $V^*$. In this way we can define isomorphism $V \rightarrow V^*$ by taking each respective basis of $V$ to $V^*$.

Now let us consider $V^{**} = \text{hom}(V^*, \mathbb{R})$. Of course this is also a vector space of dimension $r$ and we can construct an isomorphism from $V$ to $V^{**}$ by taking their basis. However, we can define a more slick isomorphism $\Gamma: V \rightarrow V^{**}$ thus, (with $\phi \in V^*$)

$$
(\Gamma v)(\phi) = \phi (v)
$$

This isomorphism is considered more 'nature' as it does not involve on finding basis of $V$ or $V^{**}$. In comparison, no one has found an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ without using their basis yet. In this way we have $V = V^{**}$ by a more 'nature' isomorphism and thus comes the name of duality.