# Why are dual spaces called "dual spaces", even when I don't see if they're really "complements"?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, duality-theorems

Why are dual spaces called "dual spaces", even when I don't see if they're really "complements" of the original space.

In optimization the primal-dual distinction seems to rely on logical complement. That the dual of the primal is the "complement" of the primal.

Couldn't dual spaces be called e.g. "functional space of" or e.g. "bounded functional space of" space? Assuming that the primal is non-function space or e.g. "only linear functionals".

Comment: One of the most simple results that convinced me that "duality" is a good name is the fact that $$ \Vert \ell \Vert  = \sup_{\Vert x\Vert=1} |\ell(x)|, \quad \Vert x \Vert = \sup_{\Vert \ell\Vert = 1} |\ell(x)|. $$ Of course, there are many more reasons for the name duality, but I remember that this was the one that won me over.

Comment: @MisterRiemann To me that seems like I'd call it "extended space". Or e.g. "composition space".

Comment: Well sure, I just wanted to motivate why I feel that it's a good name. That motivation might not work for you as well, of course. =)

Comment: @MisterRiemann  I believe that one of the cornerstones of modern mathematics is though, reliance on definitions which are as universally as possibly intuitive.

Comment: Having worked with dual spaces for some time now, I do feel that this definition is about as intuitive as it gets. I think that the answer below explains this quite well.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1295703/173147

Answer (score 4):

The (topological) dual $X^*$ of a normed vector space $X$ is the vector space of continuous linear functionals equipped with the norm
$$\|f\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |f(x)|.$$
This leads to the inequality, $|f(x)| \le \|f\| \|x\|$.

Ideally, to call $^*$ a duality relation, we'd want it at least to be an involution, so that $X^{**} = X$ (for some definition of $=$).

We can think of each $x \in X$ as a functional $\hat{x} \in X^{**}$, defined by:
$$\hat{x} : X^* \to \Bbb{R} : f \mapsto f(x).$$
It's not hard to see that, for a fixed $x \in X$, this map is linear. Moreover, it's continuous; if we have $\|f\| \le 1$, then
$$|\hat{x}(f)| = |f(x)| \le \|f\|\|x\| \le \|x\|,$$
so this proves $\|\hat{x}\| \le \|x\|$. Using the Hahn-Banach Extension Theorem, we can find some $f$ with $\|f\| = 1$ and $f(x) = \|x\|$, which implies that $\|\hat{x}\| = \|x\|$.

So, what does this tell us? It means that this $\hat{}$ operation, mapping $X$ to $X^{**}$, maps any element of $X$ to an element of $X^{**}$. Moreover, this map doesn't change the norm, meaning that it's an isometry, and thus a continuous, injective, and invertible on its range. If it's surjective, this would mean that $X$ and $X^{**}$ are isometrically isomorphic, and so $X = X^{**}$ for a pretty good definition of $=$.

BUT, unfortunately, in general, this $\hat{}$ map is **not** surjective. The spaces for which it is surjective are known as reflexive spaces (and they are a large and important class of spaces). There are, however, spaces that are not reflexive.

Of course, every finite-dimensional space is reflexive, because $\hat{x}$ maps injectively between two spaces of the same dimension, and hence is surjective. Every Hilbert space is reflexive, as is every $L_p$ space with $1 < p < \infty$. For such spaces, $X$ and $X^{**}$ are isometrically isomorphic; they are structurally the same.

As an example of a non-reflexive space, take $X = c_0$, the space of $0$-convergent real sequences uner the supremum ($\infty$-)norm. Then $X^*$ is isometrically isomorphic to $l^1$, the space of summable sequences under the $1$-norm. The second dual $X^{**}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $l^\infty$, the space of bounded sequences under the supremum/$\infty$-norm again. This space is quite a bit larger than $c_0$!

So, it doesn't perfectly earn its title of "dual", but it does so in enough important situations that we call it a "dual" anyway.